# Blender 2.8 fails to load using NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Tags: gpu, windows

I get the following error message when trying to launch blender 2.8.
I have checked and i am running the latest drivers and my GPU says it supports OpenGL 4+

[image: Blender error message]

[image]

Comment: Please run `dxdiag` and check if your graphics card is listed in the display tab.

Comment: Also try to update the nVidia drivers

Comment: I have NVIDA Geoforce experience and it says i have the latest driver installed. I get the above information from dxdiag